# How to mantain consisten font size in different plots

Tags: fontsize, r, knitr

I usually embed numerous `R` plots in my TeX documents. `knitr` is very handy in helping me producing plots using the same font family of the TeX document. But a different problem of consistency is given by the font *size*: still I haven't found a way to maintain the same font size independently from the size of the containing box. For instance I might have a plot that extends horizontally over 90 percent of the paper width and then another that will only extends over 45 percent; usually this will result in plots with different font sizes. I can of course go back to the `R` script and tweak the size values until I get the right size but I wonder if there's a smarter solution to set the font size of the plots for the whole document without modifying the plots' source scripts.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/tikzdevice/](tikzdevice).

Comment: The original maintainer of tikzDevice is no longer actively maintaining this package, so we are trying to take it over: https://github.com/yihui/tikzDevice (You can install from http://rforge.net/tikzDevice/) knitr has built-in support for tikzDevice; see example 059 for an example: https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples For more: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/graphics/

Comment: Great news you are taking the package over. Communities of users usually don't say thanks, but I do.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the tikzDevice-Package for R?

It lets you create *.tex files to import into latex
like this:

```
library(tikzDevice)

options(tikzMetricPackages = c("\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}", 
                               "\\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}"))
tikz("your directory/graph.tex", width=3,height=3)
plot(runif(10))
legend("topright","this text should not scale")
dev.off()
```

Then you can input it in your latex-code, using the package "tikz", where you can use \tikzset to scale the picture. The fontsize stays the same.

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \tikzset{every picture/.append style={scale=0.4}}
    \include{graph}
     \caption{a nice graph}
     \label{graph}
   \end{figure}
```

`